# AWK - pattern recognition

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

So I have this file, horribly formatted:

```
cat file1 

220914230708E2022091416195068167642220000039TE  OKaaaaaaaaaa          0000000017316354827094010600 aaaaaaaaaa               001                                  2022091416123467540807620001105TE  OKbbbbbbbbbb          0000000292934354487119918680 bbbbbbbbbb               001                                  2022091416483567002141420000731TE  OKDFDFJFSDFHS          0000000199137867325032383540                                                                2022091419204463543285020000412TE  OKcccccccccc          0000000111113867351043007780 cccccccccc               1EP                                  2022091419372363503707220000233TE  OKddddddddddd          0000000067822353828105648630 ddddddddddd               001
```

And I would like to make it more readable.

I noticed the first field always ends up with "TE", so I tried this (and it almost worked).

```
awk ' BEGIN { RS = "TE" } { if ( $0 ~ "OK" ) print "TE" $0 }' file1

TE  OKaaaaaaaaaa          0000000017316354827094010600 aaaaaaaaaa               001                                  2022091416123467540807620001105
TE  OKbbbbbbbbbb          0000000292934354487119918680 bbbbbbbbbb               001                                  2022091416483567002141420000731
TE  OKDFDFJFSDFHS          0000000199137867325032383540                                                                2022091419204463543285020000412
TE  OKcccccccccc          0000000111113867351043007780 cccccccccc               1EP                                  2022091419372363503707220000233
TE  OKddddddddddd          0000000067822353828105648630 ddddddddddd               001
```

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
2022091416123467540807620001105TE               OKbbbbbbbbbb            0000000292934354487119918680    bbbbbbbbbb               001                                  
2022091416483567002141420000731TE               OKDFDFJFSDFHS           0000000199137867325032383540                                                                
2022091419204463543285020000412TE               OKcccccccccc            0000000111113867351043007780    cccccccccc               1EP                                  
2022091419372363503707220000233TE               OKddddddddddd           0000000067822353828105648630    ddddddddddd              001
```

I know the problem is that I'm not correctly identifying the pattern, but I'm not sure what to do next.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Using `awk` + `column` combination here to get the values in exact tabular format.

```
awk '
BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
{ $1=$1 }
1
' <(awk '{gsub(/[^[:space:]]+TE[[:space:]]+/,"\n&");sub(/^\n/,"")} 1' Input_file) | 
column -t -s $'\t'
```

***OR*** to test code with condition which is having to check line has `OK` string or not try:

```
awk '
BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
/OK/{ $1=$1; print}
' <(awk '{gsub(/[^[:space:]]+TE[[:space:]]+/,"\n&");sub(/^\n/,"")} 1' Input_file) | 
column -t -s $'\t'
```

Comment: To use code in one-liner form use like: `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {$1=$1} 1' <(awk '{gsub(/[^[:space:]]+TE[[:space:]]+/,"\n&");sub(/^\n/,"")} 1' Input_file) | column -t -s $'\t'`.

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} /OK/{ $1=$1; print}' <(awk '{gsub(/[^[:space:]]+TE[[:space:]]+/,"\n&");sub(/^\n/,"")} 1' Input_file) | column -t -s $'\t'` To use code in on-liner with checking condition if line contains `OK` try this one.

Answer (score 3):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
220914230708E2022091416195068167642220000039TE  OKaaaaaaaaaa          0000000017316354827094010600 aaaaaaaaaa               001                                  2022091416123467540807620001105TE  OKbbbbbbbbbb          0000000292934354487119918680 bbbbbbbbbb               001                                  2022091416483567002141420000731TE  OKDFDFJFSDFHS          0000000199137867325032383540                                                                2022091419204463543285020000412TE  OKcccccccccc          0000000111113867351043007780 cccccccccc               1EP                                  2022091419372363503707220000233TE  OKddddddddddd          0000000067822353828105648630 ddddddddddd               001
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[0-9]*TE"}/OK/{print prev, $0}{prev=RT}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
2022091416195068167642220000039TE   OKaaaaaaaaaa          0000000017316354827094010600 aaaaaaaaaa               001                                  
2022091416123467540807620001105TE   OKbbbbbbbbbb          0000000292934354487119918680 bbbbbbbbbb               001                                  
2022091416483567002141420000731TE   OKDFDFJFSDFHS          0000000199137867325032383540                                                                
2022091419204463543285020000412TE   OKcccccccccc          0000000111113867351043007780 cccccccccc               1EP                                  
2022091419372363503707220000233TE   OKddddddddddd          0000000067822353828105648630 ddddddddddd               001
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that row separator is zero-or-more (`*`) digits (`[0-9]`) followed by `TE`, then for line containing `OK` I print prev and current line (`$0`) where prev denotes row terminator (`RT`) of previous line, which is set *after* said printing. **Disclaimer**: my output has line with `OKaaaaaaaaaa` unlike desired output stipulated as I do not know what is logic behind it banishment, feel to adjust condition of `print`ing action to take this into account.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 2):

I like @Daweo's answer best. An iterative solution that would work with any awk:

```bash
awk '
  function emit() {
    if (line ~ /OK/) print line
    line = ""
  }
  {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      if (i > 1 && $i ~ /TE$/) emit()
      line = line $i " "
    }
    emit()
  }
' file | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're okay with 2 `awk` calls with a pipe, then here's an `awk`-based solution without needing `custom functions`, `loops`, `arrays`, `END` block, or vendor-proprietary solutions :

```
mawk 'gsub("[^ \t]+TE", "\n&") + sub("^\n[^E]+E",_)^_' | mawk NF=NF OFS='\t'
```

|

```
2022091416195068167642220000039TE   OKaaaaaaaaaa    0000000017316354827094010600    aaaaaaaaaa  001
2022091416123467540807620001105TE   OKbbbbbbbbbb    0000000292934354487119918680    bbbbbbbbbb  001
2022091416483567002141420000731TE   OKDFDFJFSDFHS   0000000199137867325032383540
2022091419204463543285020000412TE   OKcccccccccc    0000000111113867351043007780    cccccccccc  1EP
2022091419372363503707220000233TE   OKddddddddddd   0000000067822353828105648630    ddddddddddd 001
```